# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mealpy.root'

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a code and it is giving me the following error..

from mealpy.root import Root

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mealpy.root'

I tried various commands to solve this.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: the module is installed on your device? If not try Try: pip install mealpy or pip3 install mealpy

Comment: Checked the different releases of this library for you. If you install version 1.2.2, your import line will work, but it does not work with the next release (2.0.0). So downgrade your version, or study the new API.